# How to set a Theme to a Gtk# application

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I would like to know how to set Theme styles from a Gtk-Sharp application.

I'm giving a try to MonoDevelop 4 in both OpenSuse 11.4 and a new 12.3 and writing a very simple gtk# app.

The app is just a "hello world" with a button.

In the designer it looks like this, with the rounded button look and everything:

[image]

But as soon as I run the app in the old OpenSuse 11.4 it looks like this with the square button look:

[image]

It looks "rounded" on the newer OpenSuse 12.3 so I understand I'm not setting some sort of Window style.

I tried with this but it didn't change anything so I'm missing the whole point here.

```
Gtk.Settings.Default.ThemeName = "Clearlooks";
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct way to set a theme, maybe you don't have the "Clearlooks" theme or its theme engine installed for GTK+ 2.

In general GTK+ apps are not expected to set custom themes for themselves, they're supposed to use the system-configured theme. Perhaps a GTK+ 2 theme is not correctly configured/installed for your openSUSE 11.4 system - check how other GTK+ 2 apps look.